# hidden labels via LINQ or HTML Helper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html, linq, hidden-field

I have been asked to simply include a label tag for both the "username" and "password" form fields on this site. This would be incredibly easy, except I'm not familiar with LINQ. I found the correct syntax, and have added the labels using:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName)
```

and

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password)
```

Now I need to make these hidden-field elements, which I don't know how the syntax in LINQ. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Also, that's not LINQ.  That is a lambda expression.  Linq also frequently uses lambdas, but Linq is a completely separate technology.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Username)
```

and

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Password)
```

Comment: This creates a hidden INPUT field. He only wants a label.

Comment: This will help me get to where I need to be down the line regadless, so thanks for the help! For now I created a class in CSS which hides things using "not so conventional" methods but does the trick for now.